# AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've tried suggested different options in different tickets but nothing worked out me and getting this error

`AbstractController::DoubleRenderError` (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".)

Can you please let me know what is wrong in this code,

```
def show
  es = @external_search

  if es.search_type == 'internal' && ['json','xml'].include?(params[:format])
    rs = @external_search.resume_search
    smws = rs.connection.daxtra_smws
    dax_xml_resp = RestClient.post(smws.hostaddress__c + 'ws/dispatch',es.request_input,{:content_type => 'text/xml',  :accept => 'application/xml', :timeout=> 90})

    cIds = []
    cHash = Hash.new
    results = []

    search_results = process_results(dax_xml_resp)
    cIds = cIds.concat(search_results[:candidate_ids]).uniq
    cHash = cHash.merge(search_results[:hash])
    results = results.concat(search_results[:results]).uniq unless search_results[:results].nil?
    if(!es.match_vacancy_id.blank?)
      match_results = search_results
    end
    #if !es.match_vacancy_id.nil?
      #match_results = process_results(es.daxtra_match_vacancy[:response].body) rescue nil
      #unless match_results.nil?
        #cIds = cIds.concat(match_results[:candidate_ids]).uniq
        #cHash = cHash.merge(match_results[:hash])
        #results = results.concat(match_results[:results]).uniq unless match_results[:results].nil?
      #end
    #end

    resume_results = []
    fields_needed = []

    if !es.fields_to_select.blank?
      fields_needed = ['Id','TR1__External_Candidate_Id__c']
      fields_needed.push(es.fields_to_select.to_s.split(','))
    end


    unless results.nil?
      tr_contacts = []
      cIds.in_groups_of(1000){|group|
        processed_group = group.compact.reject(&:blank?)
        #tr_contacts += rs.connection.soap(rs.session_id).find_where('Contact', TR1__External_Candidate_Id__c: processed_group, ["Id", "FirstName", "CreatedBy"]).records

        if !fields_needed.blank?
          tr_contacts += rs.connection.soap(rs.session_id).find_where('Contact', {'TR1__External_Candidate_Id__c' => processed_group} , fields_needed.uniq)
          else
          tr_contacts += rs.connection.soap(rs.session_id).find_where('Contact', {'TR1__External_Candidate_Id__c' => processed_group})
        end
      }

      tr_contacts.each {|x|
        cHash[x.TR1__External_Candidate_Id__c]["Result"]["Score"] =  "#{cHash[x.TR1__External_Candidate_Id__c]["Result"]["Score"].to_i.round}%"
        cHash[x.TR1__External_Candidate_Id__c]["Result"]["badges"] =  [{:name => 'match', :text_color => 'blue', :color => 'grey'}] if !match_results.nil? && match_results[:candidate_ids].include?(x.TR1__External_Candidate_Id__c)
        resume_result = Hash["tr-object" => x.to_hash, "match-attributes" => cHash[x.TR1__External_Candidate_Id__c]["Result"].merge({"daxtra" => cHash[x.TR1__External_Candidate_Id__c]["Result"]})]
        resume_results << resume_result
      }
    end


    if resume_results.blank?
        es.status_line1 = "<strong>#{es.name}</strong>"
        es.retry = 0
        es.result_count = 0
      else
        es.status_line1 = "<strong title='#{resume_results.size} Result(s)'>#{es.name}</strong>"
        es.result_count = resume_results.size
        es.retry = 0
    end
    es.status_line2 = "<div title='[Ref:#{es.id}] #{es.message}'>Status: <strong>Ready</strong></div>"

    #h = Hash["a" => 100, "contact-array" => ca]
    response_hash = {:ResumeSearch=>{:Status=>{:Code=>"100", :Description=>"OK"}, :data=>{:result=> resume_results}}}

    #rs.connection.soap(rs.session_id).update('TR1__ResumeSearch__c', Id: rs.id, TR1__result_url__c: request.fullpath) #TakingTooMuchTime

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :text => parsed_xml }
      #format.html { render :text => h.to_json }
      format.xml { 
        store_return_to
        render :xml => parsed_xml
      }
      format.json { 
        store_return_to
        render json: response_hash.to_json
      }
    end

  end

  if es.search_type == 'external' && ['json','xml'].include?(params[:format])

    url = "https://#{es.host}/jwb/dispatch?db=#{es.database}&handle=#{es.request_id}&action=search_results"
    ext_search = RestClient.get(url, :timeout => REST_TIMEOUT)
    response = JSON.parse(ext_search)
    plain = Base64.decode64(response['results'])
    dresjson = Hash.from_xml(plain)
    json_out = dresjson.to_json
    if JSON.parse(json_out)['ZZ']['cv_entry'].class == Hash
      new_json = car = {:ZZ => {:cv_entry => [JSON.parse(json_out)['ZZ']['cv_entry']]} }
      json_out = new_json.to_json
    end
    result_count = JSON.parse(json_out)['ZZ']['cv_entry'].size  unless json_out.blank? #rescue nil

    es.status_line2 = "<div title='#{es.message}'>Status: <strong>Ready</strong></div>"

    if !result_count.nil?
      es.status_line1 = "<strong title='#{es.name} - #{result_count} Result(s)'>#{es.name}</strong>"
      es.result_count = result_count
    end

    es.status_line2 = "<div title='[Ref:#{es.id}] #{es.message}'>Status: <strong>Ready</strong></div>"
    respond_to do |format|
      #format.html { render :text => response }
      #format.html { render :text => tr_contacts }
      format.xml { render :xml => plain }
      format.json { render json: json_out }
    end
  end
  es.save
  es.to_intercom
end
```

Comment: Code looks okay but what is `store_return_to` ?

Comment: `def store_return_to
    session[:return_to] = request.url
    protect
`

Comment: You have to debug by prior & post to render getting called to know exact where double render is getting called. Hope your request is processed as HTML or JSON and not as /*